# Inserir um calendário com HTML

Tags: html, asp.net, asp

Estou a tentar inserir um calendário em `HTML`, só que esse calendário está a ficar mal. O calendário é esse verde que está nesta página: https://almsaeedstudio.com/preview 
So que só me aparecem as tasks e os dias não. Que estou a fazer mal?

CODIGO QUE TENHO:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="CegosElearningReports.Report.Home" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Cegos Analytics| Home Page</title>
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
  <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
       folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/css/skins/skin-black.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../plugins/iCheck/flat/blue.css">
  <!-- Morris chart -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../plugins/morris/morris.css">
  <!-- jvectormap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css">
  <!-- Date Picker -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../plugins/datepicker/datepicker3.css">
  <!-- Daterange picker -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker-bs3.css">
  <!-- bootstrap wysihtml5 - text editor -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css">



  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 235px;
            height: 71px;
            float: none;
        }
        .auto-style2 {
            color: #0066CC;
        }
        .auto-style3 {
            font-size: medium;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
<!-- Site wrapper -->
<div class="wrapper">

  <header class="main-header">
    <!-- Logo -->
      <a href="../../index2.html" class="logo">
      <span class="logo-lg"><b>
      <img alt="aa" class="auto-style1" longdesc="aa" src="../Images/^082594892CD6A1E2D2CF4B7361463D84FEF2B4C6FEBD2707B5^pimgpsh_fullsize_distr.png" /></b></span>
    </a>
    <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
      <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
      <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>

      <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

          <!-- User Account: style can be found in dropdown.less -->
          <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <img src="/Images/user_settings.png" class="user-image" alt="User Image">
              <span class="hidden-xs">User</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <!-- User image -->
              <li class="user-header">
                <img src="/Images/user_settings.png" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">

                <%--<p>
                  Alexander Pierce - Web Developer
                  <small>Member since Nov. 2012</small>
                </p>
              </li>
              <!-- Menu Body -->
              <li class="user-body">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                    <a href="#">Followers</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                    <a href="#">Sales</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                    <a href="#">Friends</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
              </li>--%>
              <!-- Menu Footer-->
              <li class="user-footer">
                <div class="pull-left">
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Profile</a>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right">
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Sign out</a>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <!-- Control Sidebar Toggle Button -->
          <%--<li>
            <a href="#" data-toggle="control-sidebar"><i class="fa fa-gears"></i></a>
          </li>--%>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <!-- =============================================== -->

  <!-- Left side column. contains the sidebar -->
  <aside class="main-sidebar">
    <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
    <section class="sidebar">
      <!-- Sidebar user panel -->
      <div class="user-panel">
       <%-- <div class="pull-left image">--%>
          <img src="/Images/user_settings.png" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
            <span class="fa-inverse">User</span>
        <%--</div>--%>

      </div>
      <!-- search form -->
          <!-- /.search form -->
      <!-- sidebar menu: : style can be found in sidebar.less -->
      <ul class="sidebar-menu">

        <li class="treeview">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="/Images/home_menu.png" class="img-circle" alt="Home"><br />
              <span class="auto-style3">Home</span> 
          </a>
          <ul class="treeview-menu">

             </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="treeview">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="/Images/graphic_menu.png" class="img-circle" alt="Admin Tools"><br />
            <span>Admin Tools</span>

          </a>

        </li>
        <li>
            <li class="treeview">
          <a href="../widgets.html">
            <img src="/Images/graphic_menu.png" class="img-circle" alt="Reports"><br />
            <span>Reports</span>

          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="treeview">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="/Images/graphic_menu.png" class="img-circle" alt="X-Domain Reports"><br />
            <span>X-Domain Reports</span>

          </a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    <!-- /.sidebar -->
  </aside>

  <!-- =============================================== -->

  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <h3>
          Home</h3>

    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">

       <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="box box-widget widget-user-2">
            <!-- Add the bg color to the header using any of the bg-* classes -->
            <div class="widget-user-header bg-default">
              <div class="widget-user-image">
                &nbsp;</div>
              <!-- /.widget-user-image -->
              <h3 class="widget-user-username">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <img class="img-circle" src="/Images/user_settings.png" alt="User Avatar">&nbsp;&nbsp; </h3>
                <h3 class="widget-user-username">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; User</h3>
              <h5 class="widget-user-desc">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Role</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="box-footer no-padding">
              <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
                <li> <strong>&nbsp;Last Update:</strong></li>
                <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Change Password" Font-Bold="True" Width="134px"/>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Sign Out" Font-Bold="True"/>
                    &nbsp;
                  </li>
              </ul>
                </div>

            </div>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.6.1/fullcalendar.min.css' />
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.6.1/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>


<div id='calendar'></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
    })

});
    </script>




            <div class="box box-solid box-default">
            <div class="box-header">
              <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>

              <h3 class="box-title">Calendar</h3>
              <!-- tools box -->
              <div class="pull-right box-tools">
                <!-- button with a dropdown -->
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Add new event</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Clear events</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">View calendar</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
              <!-- /. tools -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body no-padding">
              <!--The calendar -->
              <div id="calendar" style="width: 100%"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
            <div class="box-footer text-black">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <!-- Progress bars -->
                  <div class="clearfix">
                    <span class="pull-left">Task #1</span>
                    <small class="pull-right">90%</small>
                  </div>
                  <div class="progress xs">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-green" style="width: 90%;"></div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="clearfix">
                    <span class="pull-left">Task #2</span>
                    <small class="pull-right">70%</small>
                  </div>
                  <div class="progress xs">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-green" style="width: 70%;"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col -->
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="clearfix">
                    <span class="pull-left">Task #3</span>
                    <small class="pull-right">60%</small>
                  </div>
                  <div class="progress xs">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-green" style="width: 60%;"></div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="clearfix">
                    <span class="pull-left">Task #4</span>
                    <small class="pull-right">40%</small>
                  </div>
                  <div class="progress xs">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-green" style="width: 40%;"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col -->
              </div>
              <!-- /.row -->
            </div>
          </div>

    </div>
           <div class="col-md-6">
          <!-- Horizontal Form -->
          <div class="box box-default" style="text-align: justify">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
              <h3 class="box-title" style="font-size: xx-large"><strong>Welcome</strong></h3>
            </div>
              <div class="text-justify">
                  <div style="float: left; width: 520px;">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
              Fusce nisi urna,&nbsp;elementum sed arcu venenatis, ultricies commodo
                  enim. 
              Suspendisse sit amet nibh iaculis purus blandit 
                      mattis vitae vitae enim. 
              Pellentesque mauris mauris,
                      <br />
                      fermentum a libero id, viverra dapibus elit. 
                      Morbi malesuada nec sem ut tempus. Praesent nec risus nibh.Pellentesque lobortis, quam vitae ornare convallis, 
                      <br />
                      risus leo pellentesque diam, eget rhoncus augue turpis sit amet ante. 
                       </div>
                  <div style="float:right;">
                 <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
                  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="item active">
                    <img src="/Images/Cegos Slider1.jpg" alt="First slide">

                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                    <img src="/Images/Cegos Slider2.jpg" alt="Second slide">

                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                    <img src="/Images/Cegos Slider3.jpg" alt="Third slide">

                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
                  <span class="fa fa-angle-left"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
                  <span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span>
                     </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <br />
          </div>

          <!-- /.box -->
        </div>
               <%--<br />--%>
               <!-- TO DO List -->
          <div class="box box-default">
            <div class="box-header">
                              <i class="ion ion-clipboard"></i>

              <h3 class="box-title">To Do List</h3>

              <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                <ul class="pagination pagination-sm inline">
                  <li><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body">
              <ul class="todo-list">
                <li>
                  <!-- drag handle -->
                      <span class="handle">
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                      </span>
                  <!-- checkbox -->
                  <input type="checkbox" value="" name="">
                  <!-- todo text -->
                  <span class="text"></span>
                  <!-- Emphasis label -->
                  <small class="label label-danger"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></small>
                  <!-- General tools such as edit or delete-->
                  <div class="tools">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                      <span class="handle">
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                      </span>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="" name="">
                  <span class="text"></span>
                  <small class="label label-info"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></small>
                  <div class="tools">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                      <span class="handle">
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                      </span>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="" name="">
                  <span class="text"></span>
                  <small class="label label-warning"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></small>
                  <div class="tools">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                      <span class="handle">
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                      </span>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="" name="">
                  <span class="text"></span>
                  <small class="label label-success"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></small>
                  <div class="tools">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                      <span class="handle">
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                      </span>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="" name="">
                  <span class="text"></span>
                  <small class="label label-primary"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></small>
                  <div class="tools">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                      <span class="handle">
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                      </span>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="" name="">
                  <span class="text"></span>
                  <small class="label label-default"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></small>
                  <div class="tools">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
            <div class="box-footer clearfix no-border">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add item</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.box -->



        <!-- /.col -->
       </div>
        </div>

    <div> 







    </div>



        </div>

            </form>

              </div>
               </div>

           </div>
      </div>

  <!-- /.box -->

    <%-- <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header">
              <i class="ion ion-clipboard"></i>--%>


          <!-- /.box -->


    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->

  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->

  <footer class="main-footer">
    <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
      <b>Version</b> 1.0.0
    </div>
    <strong>                         Copyright &copy; 2016-2017 <span class="auto-style2">Cegos Analytics</span>.</strong> All rights
    reserved.
  </footer>

<%--  <!-- Control Sidebar -->
  <aside class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark">
    <!-- Create the tabs -->
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
      <!-- Home tab content -->
      <!-- /.tab-pane -->
      <!-- Stats tab content -->
      <div class="tab-pane" id="control-sidebar-stats-tab"></div>
      <!-- /.tab-pane -->
      <!-- Settings tab content -->
      <div class="tab-pane" id="control-sidebar-settings-tab">
          <!-- /.form-group -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.tab-pane -->
    </div>
  </aside>
  <!-- /.control-sidebar -->
  <!-- Add the sidebar's background. This div must be placed
       immediately after the control sidebar -->
  <div class="control-sidebar-bg"></div>
</div>--%>
<!-- ./wrapper -->

<!-- jQuery 2.2.0 -->
<script src="../../plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
<script src="../../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- SlimScroll -->
<script src="../../plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<!-- FastClick -->
<script src="../../plugins/fastclick/fastclick.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="../../dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
<script src="../../dist/js/demo.js"></script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ta difícil de entender oque você quer, pelo que eu entendi você quer um código que mostre a data atual, correto?

Comment: Não. Quero colocar no meu website um calendario igual ao que esta na página que mandei no link esse verde  https://almsaeedstudio.com/preview. Só que quando copiei so me aparecem as tasks e nao os dias

Comment: Alguem me ajude por favor?~

Answer (score 0):

Se o calendário que se refere é o [desta página](https://almsaeedstudio.com/preview), ele está utilizando o [FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) para isso.

Para utilizar em seu site, basta fazer [o download da página ou utilizar a cnd.](http://fullcalendar.io/download/)

Um exemplo básico ficaria assim:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
    })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.6.1/fullcalendar.min.css' />
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.6.1/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>


<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Claro, no site ele está utilizando o [outras funções para criar os eventos](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/dropping/) e modificou o `CSS` para ficar "mais bonito", mas isso é tudo questão de customização.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta mas ainda não consegui fazer isso. No meu código o que voce acrescentaria/melhoraria para conseguir obter o calendario? Ainda nao consegui obter o calendario. Obrigado

Comment: @NelsonSoares Em seu código você não está referenciando o FullCalendar em parte alguma. Olhe os scripts que tem na resposta, você precisa deles para ele funcionar.

Comment: @NelsonSoares Adicione a mesma coisa da minha resposta em seu código que irá funcionar, após isso, você terá que estudar o framework para adequar a sua necessidade. Isso não tem como te ajudar assim. Mas vá perguntando de acordo com suas dúvidas.

Comment: Eu ja adicionei o seu código mas mesmo assim não está aparecendo. Eu vou postar o código que alterei para voce dar uma olhada e ver se fiz bem. Obrigado

Comment: @NelsonSoares Você possui duas div's com o `id="calendar"`. O `id` do elemento deve ser único.

Comment: Já eliminei uma div mas ainda não tive sucesso. Coloquei o código como você ve com seu scripts e com os links e ainda nao rola. Me ajuda por favor

Comment: @NelsonSoares Você está usando várias versões do jQuery, o que pode ocasionar conflitos. Nunca coloque os scripts no meio do código, deixe no início ou no final, dependendo do que for usar. Abra o console do navegador (F12) e veja se aparece algum erro.

Comment: Ja coloquei o codigo no final. MAs ainda nao obtive sucesso. Tem de instalar alguma coisa no navegador?

Comment: @NelsonSoares Se não aparece é porque está com algum erro. Aperte F12, vá na aba console, veja o erro que aparece e corrija-o.

Comment: Sim tem dois erros iguais que dizem: Browser Link : Failed to invoke return value callback. Security error: the operation is insecure. São os dois erros iguais. Me ajuda a corrigir @Randrade

Comment: @NelsonSoares Remova tudo que não for `CSS` e que não tiver a ver com o FullCalendar. Algum script seu está impedindo o funcionamento. Depois de funcionar, vá adicionando cada script até achar o problema.

Comment: Ja fiz isso. removi e adicionei novamente. Deixei comentado dois que ele estava dando erro de get. Mas esta ainda me dando um erro de: GMT+001(GMT STANDARD TIME) faile to invoke return value callback. The operation is insecure. Consegue-me ajudar nesse?

Comment: @NelsonSoares Não. Não sei quais arquivos você possui ai e qual está dando esse erro. Aconselho a criar uma página nova com o código da resposta e após estiver funcionando, ir adicionando os restantes de um a um. Em uma página nova, sem nenhum outro arquivo, a resposta irá funcionar.

Comment: Já percebi cara. Mas preciso de sua ajuda. no fullcalendar.min.css e no fullcalendar.min.js e no moment.js esta dando erro aí e diz que é aí que a ligação não é segura. Como resolvo isso? @ Randrade

Comment: ou seja esta dando erro naqueles links que voce postou à pouco

Comment: @NelsonSoares Os links que eu passei são apenas exemplos. Vá ao site e faça os downloads dos arquivos, como indiquei na resposta. Junto você irá ver um exemplo de como funciona. E por demais, utilize o site do framework para ver o que precisa fazer, não consigo te ajudar porque não sei o que tem. Faça tudo do zero e entenda como o FullCalendar funciona, depois você conseguirá incorporar em sua página.